# How do I know if a certain JS plugin is loaded?

Tags: javascript

I am initializing a JS plugin first checking if the plugin is loaded on the page:

```
if (typeof autosize !== 'undefined') {
    autosize(document.querySelectorAll('textarea'));
}
```

The problem is that even if the plugin is not present on the page, it will return `true` if there is a DOM element with a similar ID on the same page, e.g. `<div id="autosize"></div>`. Any ideas?

Comment: This code block above should also work. I see no problem with it

Comment: What `autosize` function is doing?

Answer (score 1):

How about if it's a function?

```
if (typeof autosize === 'function') {
    autosize(document.querySelectorAll('textarea'));
}
```